# TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len() - How do i fix this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to chose a random number from the `hostnumbers.txt` file.
I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

while running this code:

```
def prev_hosting_comp_random():
        with open('hostnumbers.txt') as hosts:
                read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n')
                read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts) if x]
                return random.choice(prev_hosting_comp_random)
print(type(prev_hosting_comp_random()))
```

and the hostnumbers.txt file looks like this:

```
2312
2324
234234
1245
234
```

Can you please help me fix this?

EDIT: ERROR TRACEBACK

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 94, in <module>
    'previous_hosting_id': prev_hosting_comp_random(),
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 20, in prev_hosting_comp_random
    return random.choice(prev_hosting_comp_random)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/random.py", line 259, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: `return random.choice(prev_hosting_comp_random)` - I think you meant to choose from something else there.

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll update error traceback

Comment: Just use your list `random.choice(read_hosts )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant

```
def prev_hosting_comp_random():
        with open('file.txt') as hosts:
                read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n')
                read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts) if x]
                return random.choice(read_hosts)
```

because `random.choice(prev_hosting_comp_random)` wont work because `prev_hosting_comp_random` is a function

Answer (score 1):

`return random.choice(prev_hosting_comp_random)` seems wrong, as it is indeed a function as the error message said. You probably want to replace it by
`return random.choice(read_hosts)`

Comment: I want to return a random number from my text file